# Default html tooltip on double monitor is displayed at incorrect position

Tags: html, google-chrome, tooltip, microsoft-edge

I have a simple HTML code as below and I have an ACER laptop (1290x1080). When I run the HTML code on the chrome browser and tooltip of the HTML works fine with the primary monitor. When I use the second monitor (LG monitor) the tooltip of the title attribute is displayed at an incorrect position on chrome browser and MS Edge.

Html code like this:

```
<a title="Hello world!">Hover over me</a>
```

See the link img as below to see more detail or you can click here: [online code here](https://jsfiddle.net/z42r2vv0/2/)

[Error picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Yuo.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an error on your code. It's a Google Chrome issue that happens on a secondary screen or a multiscreen setup (but not on main screen) and appears that happens when the screen(s) have different resolutions or different scales. Look at the support forums from Google https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/60777371?hl=en

Another thread on Chrome menu issue https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/51112770?hl=en

Both problems arised a few weeks ago with an update. I also suffer from these problems. For me the new Microsoft Edge happens too but not so bad as Google Chrome. Firefox works fine. It seems that only happens on Chromium based browsers.

Comment: See Jeff Bronson's reply to the second link which has a fix for the issue: essentially need to set the high DPI setting under compatibility tab for chrome's shortcut to be "System" rather than the default "Application"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the container element for the link and try to set the tooltip text position according to it may help to fix the issue.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Top Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference:

Scroll to [Positioning Tooltips](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your response Deepak-MSFT. My issue is the default HTML tooltip on the double screen monitor.

Comment: Can you please tell me what happens if you remove the CSS code that you had applied for the tool tip? does tool tip displays correctly after that?